# ASP.NET MVC: Why my custom ActionFilter changes my HTTP response code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter, actionfilterattribute, custom-action-filter

I've developed a custom action filter in order to use it for logging response of my web-service in ASP.NET MVC.
However I don't know why when I add this action filter to my method, HTTP status response of my controller changes to 500 and it returns the message: `500 Intenal Server Error`. I put all logic inside try catch block but still problem persists.

Here is my custom ActionFilter:

```
public class LogActionFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        try
        {
            Log("OnActionExecuting", actionExecutedContext);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }


    private void Log(string methodName, HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string resopnseBody = getBodyFromResponse(context);
            HttpResponseMessage response = context.Response;
            var headers = response.Headers;
            var content = response.Content;
            var actionName = response.ToString();
            var message = "";
            message = String.Format("response:{0}", resopnseBody);

            Debug.WriteLine(message, "");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    private string getBodyFromResponse(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        string data;
        using (var stream = context.Response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
        {
            if (stream.CanSeek)
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
            }
            data = context.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Update:
Furthur investigating my code I found that calling `getBodyFromResponse` leads to this error. I myself suspect to part which I will try to read stream `.Result` twice however since I copied! this code from elsewhere I don't understand its logic clearly.

Update2:
Here is a sample method in my controller:

```
[LogActionFilter]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test()
{
     return Ok(new WebServiceResult { responseCode = 0, responseMessage = null });
}
```

Update 3:
replacing

```
resopnseBody = getBodyFromResponse(context);
```

with below line fixed issue but I don't know why!

```
resopnseBody = context.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: "Intenal Server Response"...are you sure you don't mean "Intenal Server Error"? That's a generic error shown in your browser when it gets a 500 response. The real error occurred on the server somewhere, if the code crashed somehow. Presumably it crashed outside your catch blocks. You'll have to check exception logs etc on the server

Comment: @ADyson It is 'Internal Server Error`. I edited my question about this. Yep, I know error 500 is a generic error response however only when I add filter to my method, it will cause this and I don't know why? And this is complete body of my action filter

Comment: Ok. But still, adding that filter is somehow causing something to crash in the pipeline, even if it's not directly within the filter itself. Like I said, check the event logs on the server in case any messages are logged there. Or if your application has any other kind of logs, check those too.

Comment: @ADyson It is running in IIS express by Visual Studio debugger and I don't know if IIS Express have any logs or not.  The action filter itself was intended to log output which lead to crashes :D Besieds I found the root cause of error. I will update my question.

Comment: set breakpoints to help you locate the issue. set one at start of your log, then move from there. if the breakpoints gets hit then you know your code is getting that far.

Comment: @MrLu My code goes to the end without any exceptions however I don't understand during reading response stream how my actions will ruin output and cause server errors.

Comment: @VSB Show us the controller.

Comment: Nevermind, do a breakpoints on getBodyFromResponse

Comment: @MrLu Breakpoint is get triggered and everything goes well and no exception is raised

Comment: You said calling getBodyFromResponse leads to error... I'm going to test your code, you might get an answer from someone else before i'm back. But i'll post my findings anyways.

Comment: I don't think you can just read a stream twice like you did in your initial example

Comment: Yeah i removed the stream, it seems that was causing the issue, see the answer.

Comment: Just noticed you fixed it before i posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to run by removing some lines from getBodyFromResponseAsync

```
private string getBodyFromResponseAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{
    return context.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

I hope the result is what you need.